# adding content to webview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am writing an app in which there is a tab bar and it got 5 tabs, I placed UIWebView on top of that tabs using Interface Builder. Now I want to add some content (webpages) to that webview. Any help pls.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView implements the following methods to load content:

- -(void)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
- -(void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
- -(void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL

The first two are most straight-forward for remote and local content, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

This will tell you everything you need to know and as per much of Apple's documentation, there's quite a few code samples attached so you can look at concrete implementations. (See the "Related sample code" section.)